# VXG Media Player giving Unknown error in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp

I want to play RTSP link in my webpage. for that I am using VXG Media Player to play RTSP link video.

I am testing in Chrome browser

below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/vxgplayer-1.8.33.js"></script>
<link href="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/vxgplayer-1.8.33.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>  
  <body>
  <div class="vxgplayer"
             id="vxg_media_player1"
             url="rtmp://5.101.139.34:1935/vod/Naam_Shahana.mp4"
             autostart controls avsync
             nmf-src="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/pnacl/Release/media_player.nmf"
             nmf-path="media_player.nmf"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

[I have taken reference from this url](https://www.videoexpertsgroup.com/vxg-chrome-plugin/)

I am getting error like below screenshot,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Init your player

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/vxgplayer-1.8.33.js"></script>
  <link href="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/vxgplayer-1.8.33.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>  
<body>
 <div class="vxgplayer"
         id="vxg_media_player1"
         url="rtmp://5.101.139.34:1935/vod/Naam_Shahana.mp4"
         autostart controls avsync
         nmf-src="~/vxgplayer-1.8.33/pnacl/Release/media_player.nmf"
         nmf-path="media_player.nmf"></div>
 <script>
   var player = vxgplayer('vxg_media_player1');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

See more here https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/VXG.Chrome-RTSP-Player/blob/master/src/index.html